# ssh, read content of a command

Tags: php, ssh

I got this error trying to excute a command over an ssh server

> Warning: stream_get_contents(): Failure 'transport read' (-43) in C:\wamp\www\monitor\test.php on line 12

Here is my code

```
<?php
$conn = ssh2_connect("xx.ss.xx.s", 22);
if(!(ssh2_auth_password($conn, "blbla", "blbla"))){
     die('Authentication Failed...');
} else {
    echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
 $stream = ssh2_exec($conn, "dis inter");
 stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
 $result= stream_get_contents($stream);
 echo $result;
 stream_set_timeout($stream, 10);
   fclose($stream);
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the value of $stream? -43?

Comment: @ Oliver sorry i don't understand what you mean? can you rephrase? am not too familier with these function

Comment: $stream is your variable which you are filling with the return of the ssh2_exec